# How can I display the username of a forum?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find out how I can display the username of a user. For example user admin posts a forum, then I would see **Created By: admin** on the forum page, instead I can only fish out the ID.

I don't know a much about mongoose and I need someone who is familiar with it.

**My Forum Model:**

You see I have only ref: 'user' and this is grabbing the ObjectId("") from the User.

```
const forumSchema = ({
   forumName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   forumDescription: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   user: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user'
   },
   published_on: {
      type: String,
      default: moment().format("LLL")
   },
});
```

**my userModel:**

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   userID: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   isAdministrator: {
      type: Boolean,
      deafult: false,
  },

});
```

**Front-end :**

As you can see only in `{forum.user}` there I can see the id from the user but I want his name not the id

```
 <footer className="blockquote-footer">
    Created by:{forum.user}
    Created on:{forum.published_on.substring(0,300)}
 </footer>
```

Comment: Can you post the method responsible for returning the forum object on the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 'ref' to reference the user table. When you are fetching a forum document, use the populate() function in mongoose to get all the user details as a sub-object to the forum document.

example: `forumShcema.find({_id:<forum_id>}).populate('user').exec()`

Comment: I created a Forum but there is only the object Id of the user nothing more in the database